# How can i simulate random robot keypress in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, netbeans, robotframework

I am making some kind of bot with selenium. There is a point where i want to simulate random KeyPress and KeyRelease with robot class. It would be a random of String i declared. The reason why i want this is because i select a dropdown menu and then i want to select randomly an option every time bot starts. Here is how far i came:

```
 Random r = new Random();
 String alphabet = "abcdfhijlnpsu".toUpperCase();

 Robot robot = new Robot();

 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.HERE I WANT TO SIMULATE RANDOM KEY PRESS FROM STRING alphabet);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.HERE I WANT TO RELEASE A PREVIOUSLY PRESSED BUTTON THAT WAS RANDOMLY CHOOSEN);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 String s = "foobar42"; //Target String
 int l = (int)(Math.random()*s.length());
 char ch = s.charAt(l); //ch will be a random character from given String
```

Above line could be replaced by given line

```
int l = new Random().nextInt(s.length());
```

Updated : You can use `swith case` to accomplish the task

```
switch (ch) {
        case 'a': doType(VK_A); break;
        case 'b': doType(VK_B); break;
        case 'c': doType(VK_C); break;
        case 'd': doType(VK_D); break;
        case 'e': doType(VK_E); break;
        case 'f': doType(VK_F); break;
        case 'g': doType(VK_G); break;
        case 'h': doType(VK_H); break;
        case 'i': doType(VK_I); break;
        case 'j': doType(VK_J); break;
        case 'k': doType(VK_K); break;
        case 'l': doType(VK_L); break;
        case 'm': doType(VK_M); break;
        case 'n': doType(VK_N); break;
        case 'o': doType(VK_O); break;
        case 'p': doType(VK_P); break;
        case 'q': doType(VK_Q); break;
        case 'r': doType(VK_R); break;
        case 's': doType(VK_S); break;
        case 't': doType(VK_T); break;
        case 'u': doType(VK_U); break;
        case 'v': doType(VK_V); break;
        case 'w': doType(VK_W); break;
        case 'x': doType(VK_X); break;
        case 'y': doType(VK_Y); break;
        case 'z': doType(VK_Z); break;
        case 'A': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_A); break;
        case 'B': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_B); break;
        case 'C': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_C); break;
        case 'D': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_D); break;
        case 'E': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_E); break;
        case 'F': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_F); break;
        case 'G': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_G); break;
        case 'H': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_H); break;
        case 'I': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_I); break;
        case 'J': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_J); break;
        case 'K': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_K); break;
        case 'L': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_L); break;
        case 'M': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_M); break;
        case 'N': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_N); break;
        case 'O': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_O); break;
        case 'P': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_P); break;
        case 'Q': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Q); break;
        case 'R': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_R); break;
        case 'S': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_S); break;
        case 'T': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_T); break;
        case 'U': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_U); break;
        case 'V': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_V); break;
        case 'W': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_W); break;
        case 'X': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_X); break;
        case 'Y': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Y); break;
        case 'Z': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Z); break;
        case '`': doType(VK_BACK_QUOTE); break;
        case '0': doType(VK_0); break;
        case '1': doType(VK_1); break;
        case '2': doType(VK_2); break;
        case '3': doType(VK_3); break;
        case '4': doType(VK_4); break;
        case '5': doType(VK_5); break;
        case '6': doType(VK_6); break;
        case '7': doType(VK_7); break;
        case '8': doType(VK_8); break;
        case '9': doType(VK_9); break;
        case '-': doType(VK_MINUS); break;
        case '=': doType(VK_EQUALS); break;
        case '~': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_BACK_QUOTE); break;
        case '!': doType(VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK); break;
        case '@': doType(VK_AT); break;
        case '#': doType(VK_NUMBER_SIGN); break;
        case '$': doType(VK_DOLLAR); break;
        case '%': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_5); break;
        case '^': doType(VK_CIRCUMFLEX); break;
        case '&': doType(VK_AMPERSAND); break;
        case '*': doType(VK_ASTERISK); break;
        case '(': doType(VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS); break;
        case ')': doType(VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS); break;
        case '_': doType(VK_UNDERSCORE); break;
        case '+': doType(VK_PLUS); break;
        case '\t': doType(VK_TAB); break;
        case '\n': doType(VK_ENTER); break;
        case '[': doType(VK_OPEN_BRACKET); break;
        case ']': doType(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET); break;
        case '\\': doType(VK_BACK_SLASH); break;
        case '{': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_OPEN_BRACKET); break;
        case '}': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_CLOSE_BRACKET); break;
        case '|': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_BACK_SLASH); break;
        case ';': doType(VK_SEMICOLON); break;
        case ':': doType(VK_COLON); break;
        case '\'': doType(VK_QUOTE); break;
        case '"': doType(VK_QUOTEDBL); break;
        case ',': doType(VK_COMMA); break;
        case '<': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_COMMA); break;
        case '.': doType(VK_PERIOD); break;
        case '>': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_PERIOD); break;
        case '/': doType(VK_SLASH); break;
        case '?': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_SLASH); break;
        case ' ': doType(VK_SPACE); break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot type character " + character);
```

OR

```
String code = "VK_" + ch    
Field f = KeyEvent.class.getField(code);
int keyEvent = f.getInt(null);

robot.press(keyEvent);
robot.release(keyEvent);
```

Comment: I need Random from alphabet string content, not from int 1-50. If that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah but now i need to write it inside a             robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.RANDOMNUMBERHERE);

Comment: Updated again. This is idea, you have to manipulate it according to your need

Comment: When copying from other sources, please provide credit for original authors.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following way to do the same

```
   Random rand = new Random();
   char randomchar = (char) ('A' + Math.random() * ('Z'-'A' + 1));
   Robot robot = new Robot();

   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_+randomchar);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_+randomchar);
```

Updated :

```
    String allchars = "abcdfhijlnpsu";

    char letter = allchars.charAt(rand.nextInt(allchars.length()));
```

Comment: This will randomize whole alphabet, but i would like to exclude some chars. How could i do that?

Comment: Means  some specific limit character like A to D ?

Comment: Only this will be allowed "abcdfhijlnpsu" all others must be excluded.